# Uploading python library to server

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, setup.py

The problem is like this:

- the python on the server is version 2.4.3 (somewhat obsolete),
- numpy is version 1.2.1 (obsolete) and
- matplotlib is version 0.99.1.1
  (devastating obsolete + lacks pyplot for some unknown reason).

I cannot use shell/bash on server. How can I renew the numpy and matplotlib to current versions?

*E.g., can I upload some folders of my python install to certain server locations and they will magically work? Or something different?* 
Thank you for your attention.

P.S. I can manipulate python path on server during script execution.

Comment: can you setup a virtualenv on the server ?

Comment: No, unless there is a way to do this without command line.

Comment: a vitualenv is difficult to move unless you can reproduce the exact system of your server and install a virtualenv there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds hacky and quite possibly evil, but if you don't have shell access but do have Python access, I suppose you could write a Python script that writes the library files to the proper location.

You can determine the location by examining the `__file__` value in each module.  If this is a file system location the Python process has permissions write to (possibly the site package directory) it could be done.  If this is under a location you can't write to, then no. Be careful, this is quite hacky.

Comment: I have certain directories (cgi-bin, for example) where I can do whatever I like. Does it mean, I can just upload tarball to this location and run setup.py in some way?

Comment: That's what I would try. A lot depends on what the exact permissions are so it's hard to say yes or no without knowing those details. Experiment with that approach and you may be able to find a way. Good luck!